# How to split file with a trick in bash

Tags: bash, split

I have two question in `split` command:

1) How can we split a huge file in this format?

```
x0
x1
.
.
.
x10
.
.
.
```

2) How can we split a huge file in this format?

```
0
1
.
.
.
10
.
.
.
100
.
.
.
```

What I tried is not satisfactory because result is:

```
x00
x01
x02
.
.
.
x10
.
.
.
x100
.
.
.
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: So you need to just remove `x` from each line?

Comment: I want to remove x and start files from one numiric suffix...

Comment: It starts from x00, x001...x10...,x1000,... But I want this result: x0,x1...x10...x100

Comment: Could I give you what I mean ? :)

Comment: These are the results of split command... @timgeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question:

```
>> ls
file
>> split -a 1 -d file
>> ls
file x0 x1 x2 x3 ...
```

However, you will get

```
split: output file suffixes exhausted
```

with this method if there would be more than 9 split files. You can use

```
>> split -d file
>> ls
file x00 x01 x02 ...
```

and then use `rename`:

```
>> rename 's/^x0/x/' x0*
>> ls
file x0 x1 x2 ...
```

Second question: Use

```
split -a 1 -d file ''
```

if you will have less then 10 split files. Otherwise, use

```
split -d file ''
```

and then

```
rename 's/^0//' 0*
```